# How to test save functions in CakePHP Models?

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, model, cakephp-2.0

Just writing some tests for my CakePHP application and I am currently trying to work out the best way to test some functions in my models which end up saving data.

Should I just assertTrue or should I pull the data out of the database and assert the expected result against what is in the database?

There are some values that I have to generate programatically based on the users input so need to be sure they are write. Should I do a find operation within the test and check that the results of that are what I expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the expects to check what you save method returns. I assume you're not talking about save() because that is already tested within the core. So expect in your test whatever your method should return and see if it passes.

And yes, you can do a find within the test to check if your record was saved with the correct values. So find() it and expectEqual() on the result to whatever you expected.

By the way, it's always good to check the core tests to get an idea of how to test certain things or use mock objects. :)

Comment: Thanks! I am not testing save() - I want to test that the appropriate data is saved to the right place. As some figures are created by my application. If I check via find() though everything should be ok. :)